# Same code for AWS and local application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to create Java application with use of Amazon Web Services and I also want to have ability to run it as local application. So it will be in two versions: Amazon cloud and as local application. I don't know AWS yet and I'am worry about if there is some specific api or database access so I couldn't run as local app. I simply do not want to write two separate versions of that app, or just write as less as possible.

Is it possible?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The generic answer would be "yes, it is possible" (on EC2, you have virtual servers with root/administrator access), but since you are asking the question you might have some concerns/requirements which you didn't explain. Why wouldn't it be possible? Is your application doing something "unusual"? What is your application?

Comment: I don't know AWS yet and I'am worry about if there is some specific api or database access so I couldn't run as local app.

Comment: Then just edit your question and add this additional information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EC2, you can launch virtual servers (or *instances*) with root or administrator access. That means your EC2 instances are capable of running mostly everything you can run locally.

There are no specific APIs to learn to run Java code on EC2. Just compile and package your code, upload it to your server (using scp/rsync/anything else you might be more used to), then run it with `java -jar myapp.jar`, after installing Java on the instance. You can also upload the source code directly into your instance and compile it there if you want. It really behaves like a "normal" server.

About database access, again, it works exactly as you would expect: just install your database server on the instance, say, MySQL, and connect to it normally (using JDBC for example). Also, note that there's a service called [**Relational Database Service (RDS)**](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/), which simplifies the deployment and management of a database system: you don't have to install your database software, maintain it, upgrade, backup, etc, everything is done for you. You simply specify the name and password of the "master" user, and it gives you back a connection string. (and there's also a "micro" RDS instance which is included in the [**free tier**](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) so that you can start exploring for free!)

Finally, if you don't want to launch and maintain a virtual server by yourself, you could use [**Elastic Beanstalk**](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/), which automates lots of things for you: using the web interface, you simply upload your ".war" file, and Elastic Beanstalk launches and instance for you, installs Java, Tomcat, deploys your application, and monitor it for you -- you get emails in your inbox if anything goes wrong. There are tons of other features included in Elastic Beanstalk, and it is all completely free (you just pay for the servers it launches -- also, if you instruct it to launch at most a single t1.micro instance, which is included on the free tier, again, you pay nothing!)